# id not captured by ngRoute

Tags: angularjs, ngresource, ngroute

I have a simple Angular routing config with a home page and some user profiles. For some reason when I navigate to `/users/user_3`, the controller requests the user index route, `users.json`, instead of `users/user_3.json`. This is causing the `User` service to complain: "Error in resource configuration for action `get`. Expected response to contain an object but got an array."

This error indicates to me that `$resource` knows it's requesting a single user resource, but the route params appear to have been captured properly based on my fiddling within the console:

```
> $route = angular.element(document.body).injector().get('$route')
Object {routes: Object, reload: function, updateParams: function, current: Object}
> $route.current.params
Object {id: "user_3"}
```

So it seems like somewhere between when the route params are captured and the actual service request is made, something is causing the route param to disappear.

Here's my route config:

```
$routeProvider.when( '/', {
  controller: 'HomeCtrl',
  templateUrl: '/assets/views/home.html',
})
.when( '/users/:id', {
  controller: 'UserCtrl',
  templateUrl: '/assets/views/user.html',
});
```

My User service:

```
angular.module('amn.services').service('User', [
  '$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/users/:id.json', {
      id: '@id'
    });
  }
]);
```

...and my UserCtrl:

```
angular.module('amn.controllers').controller('UserCtrl', function($scope, User) {
  return User.get(function(data) {
    return $scope.user = data;
  });
});
```

Can anyone tell me what's going on? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using the `@` property incorrectly in this case, and never actually passing your `id` to the resource.  From the [Angular Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource):

> If the parameter value is prefixed with @ then the value for that parameter will be extracted from the corresponding property on the data object (provided when calling an action method).

In your case, you don't have an object yet, since this is a `GET` call, so there is no object to pull the `id` from.  Your call to `get()` is essentially requesting all `User` objects.  The `@` is more appropriate for `PUT`, `POST`, and `DELETE` verbs.

To correct your code, change your controller to the following:

```
angular.module('amn.controllers')
    .controller('UserCtrl', function($scope, $routeParams, User) {
    return User.get({id: $routeParams.id}, function(data) {
```